# Datapower web service proxy

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have created a WSDL file using IBM APP Connect ,and uploaded it on datapower to create a wsp however I am failing to test the same wsdl file using SOAPUI even though I redirected the endpoint to my http://ip:port/uri and put in the provided AAA credentials.

Please help, my datapower is running on docker so I am not sure if there are more configurations I still need to do before testing.

I have already created the WSP and used [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as remote endpoint

Answer (score 1):

find solution here on how to expose your docker ports to the local host.

https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006AB5M2/datapower-on-docker?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Need more clarification on this issue. Please provide xsl code.